# How to add 'checked' attribute to HTML string (with nested tags) with jQuery, returning the whole string afterwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add 'checked' attribute to HTML string, which contains multiple HTML tags.

````
let someBtn = `<div class='btn'><input type='checkbox' id='${item.Id}' 
                            value='Some value' class='active-btn'> <label class='btn' 
                            for='${item.id}'></label></div>`;```
````

Doing it this way:

```
var something = $($.parseHTML(someBtn)).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 1).prop('outerHTML');
```

returns only the  tag, not the whole updated HTML string.
Also that input tag gets `checked="checked"` attribute instead of just `checked`. Why is that? I cannot use `attr('checked', true)` - there's no method with this kind of parameters.

Could somebody please help me out with this problem - to return the whole HTML string with proper checked attribute?

Comment: *Also that input tag gets checked="checked" attribute instead of just checked. Why is that?* — Because the browser normalises it and uses the full name=value and not the shorthand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Useless to do `$($.parseHTML('html_string'))`, you can directly use `$('html_string')`.

You also need to seperate the fact to update your checkbox attributes and the fact to get the HTML.

```js
const someBtn = `<div class='btn'><input type='checkbox' id='myId' 
                            value='Some value' class='active-btn'> <label class='btn' 
                            for='myId'></label></div>`;
                           
let html = $(someBtn);

html.find('input').attr('checked', 1);

html = html.prop('outerHTML'); // or html[0].outerHTML

console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In my case prop() returns only the element selected by find().

Comment: That's why you need to divide some parts of your logic, as I did in my answer.